# How can I insert a hanger bolt into wood table leg?

Tags: woodworking

I am attaching table legs to table top with Waddell Metal Table Straight Top Plate. How can I insert a 5/16-18 X 3 in Hanger Bolt into wood table leg?

Comment: Welcome to DIYSE. The problem you're facing isn't clear. Hanger bolts have wood threads on one end. You drill and twist them in. Can you edit to clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

> **How can I insert a ... Hanger Bolt into wood**

[image: Photo of a typical hangar bolt - machine-screw one end, wood-screw at other end]

#### Plan A

I would drill a pilot hole in the wood and drive the screw-threaded part of the hanger bolt into the wood by using a spanner/wrench/socket on a double nut on the bolt-threaded portion (the second nut tightened against the first nut using a pair of spanners/wrenches to thus lock both nuts in position on the bolt). Then unlock the nuts and remove them.

You can then screw the legs into the top-plate.

#### Plan B

I suspect you could also do this by attaching the top plate to the table top, turning the top upside down, inserting the bolts into the top plates and then screwing the pre-drilled legs onto the screw. Using lubrication/strap-wrench/clamp as needed.